# jquery ui dialog retaining old values for some time

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

in my case i have a jquery ui dialog which is retaining the old values in the textbox when i close the dialog after inserting the data without submiting for some seconds and its working fine in other cases. any suggestions??

```
$("#btnAddRole").click(function ()
{


console.log(RoleAddPostBackURL);
var divDetail = $("#addRolePlace");// div to open in dialog
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: RoleAddPostBackURL,
    //traditional: true,
    contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
    //data: { "id": id },
    datatype: "html",
    success: function (data)
    {
        divDetail.html(data);
        //alert(divDetail.html());
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error: Dynamic content load failed.");
    }
});
var winW = $(window).width() - 720;
//code to open div in dialog
divDetail.dialog(
        {
            autoOpen: true, //true => false
            position: {
                position: [0,28]
            },
            height: "auto",
            width: winW,
            resizable: false,
            //position: [0, 28],
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Add New Role',
            modal: true,
            //show:
            //{ effect: "blind", duration: 1000 },

            open: function () {
                divDetail.load();//This will load div
                divDetail.css('overflow', 'hidden');
            },
            buttons:
            [

               {
                   text: "Close",
                   "class": 'btn-success',
                   click: function () {
                       $(this).dialog("close");
                   }
               }
            ]
        });
});
```

html:

```
<div id="addRolePlace">

 </div>
<script src="~/Scripts/Role.js"></script>
```

Comment: is it a textbox or What ??

Comment: yeah it is a textbox

Comment: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.RoleName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on close: function()

```
close: function () {
                        $('#RoleName').val("");
                    }
```

hope this will help.